# object() takes no parameters in django 1.10

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to allow CORS in my app, so that my cross-domain javascript client can access my API, I've installed [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). And I'm now trying to add the middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # Remove this and it works
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

However this gives me a TypeError:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

This worked fine before the django 1.10 update. Any ideas?

Comment: When you have errors after upgrading, it's worth checking the app's GitHub issues to see if it's a known problem. If that doesn't help and you ask a question on Stack Overflow, please post the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/issues/102) says that django-cors-headers is no longer supported, and suggests using [django-cors-middleware](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cors-middleware/) instead.

Answer (score 10):

If you have custom middleware and you've moved from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE, then you need to update your middleware. Details on: [this Django documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware). TL;DR, subclass from MiddlewareMixin instead of object:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class FOOMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    pass
```