# Django exception middleware: TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'm using Django 1.10 and trying to catch all exceptions with exception middleware.

The code below causes an internal server error:

```
mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    x = 1/0 # cause an exception
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',  

]
```

middleware.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception): 
        return HttpResponse("in exception")
```

I have seen these [object() takes no parameters in django 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457381/object-takes-no-parameters-in-django-1-10) and other questions talking about middleware versus middleware_classes, but I'm not sure how that applies to this case, or what I'd actually need to change to fix the issue.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Since you are using the new `MIDDLEWARE` settings, your Middleware class must accept a `get_response` argument: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

You could write your class like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception): 
        return HttpResponse("in exception")
```

You could also use the `MiddlewareMixin` to make your Middleware compatible with pre-1.10 and post-1.10 Django versions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class ExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        return HttpResponse("in exception")
```

Comment: Using `MiddlewareMixin` fixed my issue.

Comment: MiddlewareMixin in Django1.11 will not be able to determine `request.user`. It returns anonymous

Comment: How true is @Sarit 's comment and what is the fix?

Comment: @Phares At that time I was curious and do private experiment. I did not fix anything. Normally I do it in `ViewSet`

Comment: Just by adding the **`MiddlewareMixin`** works for me. Don't even need to touch the init and call functions.

Comment: Even in the Django 4.1.3 `MiddlewareMixin` is the only way I found. Do we have any other way ?

Answer (score 19):

in the newer version of Django, the middleware should be written like this

```
import datetime
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class ActiveUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            cache.set('seen_%s' % (current_user.username), now, 
                           settings.USER_LASTSEEN_TIMEOUT)
```

Comment: Could you provide the version, please? I think it might be useful information

Comment: with Django version 3.0.2

Comment: You should not use this, this is old way of doing `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin` even your import is also suggesting deprecation.